# How to implement doGet method across all JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have page1.jsp that inherits the menu.jsp page. On my servlet for page1.jsp, the doGet calls item in the database and displays it in the menu.jsp. Now when I'm going to another link it will give me an error because the doGet of the new link' servlet doesnt provide the call for items that displays in my menu.jsp. Is it the only option to provide the doGet needed at all pages?

Comment: we don't define anything related to any HTTP methods in JSPs, we do it in servlet

Comment: I don't understand anything about your question. How can a JSP inherit from another one? WHat does "my servlet for page1.jsp" mean? Show us code, explain what you're doing, and show us complete and exact error messages and stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract superclass for all the servlets that should support your menu.jsp. There you can define a final doGet method where you first perform your menu-magic and then you can delegate to an abstract method that is implemented in the extending classes.

Comment: I already solved the problem. What I did was I import my methods in my menu.jsp file. Thanks for all the replies :)

Comment: Peter, you're seriously going in the wrong direction. I recommend to think twice before continuing.